# There is a django AUTHORIZATION module?

Tags: django, django-models, authorization

I have already a django project, which does the users authentication.
Now I nedd an authorization module (for clients and groups to certain resources). I would an existing django module or api.
thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you want? what do you mean by an authorization module?

Comment: please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication . In Django you can create groups with permissions and assigned to different users

Comment: thank you @anuragal I know I can. I just would something already done.

Comment: @alessioferri20 I would a module that recognize to which group a user belong and if that group has permissions then it redirect to the request object/resource. If the user belongs to multiple users than the module takes tha permission that 'allow' the user.